# Force newline instead of execute in ipython

Tags: ipython

There are a number of questions about how to force `EXECUTE` instead of `newline` in `ipython`. But I need the opposite.  Consider:

```
In [9]: import sqlalchemy sqlalchemy.__version__
  File "<ipython-input-9-84bd5002c701>", line 1
    import sqlalchemy sqlalchemy.__version__
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

We can see that there should be two lines: ( 1 ) the `import` and ( 2 ) the `__version__` invocation.  Whatever I try I can not separate the two pieces.

One of the suggestions was `ctl-v ctl-j`: that simply did an `EXECUTE` again.

Another suggestion was `Use %edit {tag}` [Adding line breaks in ipython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13536370/adding-line-breaks-in-ipython) : That gave an even more interesting behavior:

```
n [12]: %edit _i9
Editing... done. Executing edited code...
Out[12]: 'import sqlalchemy \nsqlalchemy.__version__ \n'
```

So notice: the (`vi`) editor did its job but then `ipython` simply converted the newlines to `\n` *and did not interpret the newlines instead it concatenated them*

So what key combination will get us the `newline` here?

Comment: I don't think you can.  That requires both executing the first line, and starting the next with extra stuff.  Sometimes it works to put a `;` between commands, but not in this case.  I'd just delete or cut the `version` stuff, and reenter it after the import.

Comment: Flagging as duplicate of [Adding line breaks in ipython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13536370/adding-line-breaks-in-ipython)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pressing `Ctrl+q Ctrl-j` should do the trick.
Check this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46060692/1278365).

Comment: The correct sequence is `Ctrl-q Ctrl-j` : I corrected your answer as a freebie to you and help to additional readers.