# Editing multi line code in IPython

Tags: ipython

I wrote a few lines of code in IPython and made a minor error. Is there a way to load the whole program again to run it quickly?

Also, I am not sure how to go and edit the typo in the program. When on the last line the cursor does not move to the lines above.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link. 
([Adding line breaks in ipython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13536370/adding-line-breaks-in-ipython?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)).

Using that %edit function, I can edit my programs lines so easily like an edit a python file using vim. Hope this is helpful.