# Multi-line editing broken in IPython 7.0.1

Tags: python, shell, ipython

I'm using IPython in zsh shell and I'm having a trouble defining a function with multiple lines.

For example, in the original Python shell, I can define a function f like this:

```
>>> def f(x):
...     a = x + 1
...     return a
... 
>>>
```

When I did it in IPython, the defination ends immediately when The line 'a = x + 1' ends. It looks like this:

```
In [4]: def f(x): 
   ...:     a = x + 1                                                                                                                              

In [5]:
```

How can I fix it by changing some configuration or installing another version of IPython?

My version of Python and IPython:

```
Python 3.5.6 |Anaconda, Inc.|  
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.0.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.
```

Comment: Sorry if my question is dumb but...
Why don't you put your script into a file and then execute it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding line breaks in ipython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13536370/adding-line-breaks-in-ipython)

Comment: Are you using IPython 7.0.1 from the Anaconda distribution?  It's really new and I'm seeing the same behavior — I expect that this will be fixed asap, so `conda update --all` could be everything that is needed to fix the problem.

Comment: @SimonFromme The Q&A you referenced is from 2012 and very much water has passed under the bridge of multiline editing in IPython... so no, I don't think it's a duplicate of the present question

Comment: @Pitto Because there is this fresh new idea of interactive programming: you modify, in the enhanced interpreter, your function definition then re-execute it using the command history, things like that...  if you have not been exposed to [IPython](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html)  then you should _absolutely_ try it — also the [notebook](http://jupyter.org/) is a great feature

Comment: I know notbooks well and I see your point, @gboffi but using the interpreter to write code, imho, is just a bad idea. I'd use it only to quickly jot a tiny snippet, maybe.

Answer (score 7):

It's a [known bug](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/11334) (see also [this](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/11337)).

As it's clear from the issues I've referenced, it's not a bug with the Anaconda distribution but something that slipped into the 7.0 release of IPython.

[Matthias Bussonier](https://github.com/Carreau) suggested to use `C-o` (that is Control o) as a stop gap measure.  `C-o` opens new blank lines below the current line that you can reach and edit using the arrow keys — it's not a very satisfactory solution but for now there is no other solution (except, of course, downgrading IPython to 6.x).

Concluding,  use `C-o` to open new lines and wait for a bug fix or downgrade to IPython 6.x.

---

*Additional Info*

[Carlos Cordoba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438386/carlos-cordoba), one of the Spyder maintainers, in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53223311/function-object-in-spyder-not-working-properly/53223752#comment93344810_53223752) to [an answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53223752/2749397) says that also the `qtconsole` is affected by this bug...

Moreover the bug, fixed in the IPython 7.1 shell, is still present in the same version of `qtconsole` and the stop-gap measure I've mentioned (`Ctrl-o` to open a line below the current one) does not work in `qtconsole`.

Comment: If you use Vi bindings it is `Esc o` — or so I'm told.

Comment: In version 7.2 the issue seems to be fixed for most of the situations I encounter, although the linked bug report mentions still cases where problems occur.