# IPython ends input of indented blocks after first newline

Tags: python, ipython

In IPython, I can't enter in a multiline indented block; it ends input (switches from the `...:` prompt to the next `In [x]`), as soon as I hit enter.

For example, I'm trying to write an example implementation of Newton's method for a demonstration. I can only write the first line before it returns me to, so all I can type into IPython is this:

```
In [3]: def newton(x0, fn, epsilon=0.00001):
   ...:     x1 = x0 - fn.evalf(subs={'x': x0}) / fn.diff().evalf(subs={'x': x0})

In [4]:
```

I'm using Python 3.6.6, IPython 7.0.1, and Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: There's a bug in v7.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52775562/multi-line-editing-broken-in-ipython-7-0-1