# Why does continuation line break right after if block on ipython?

Tags: ipython

**UPDATE**: This is/was a [known bug](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/11334) on v7.

[image: issue-screenshot]
    *Runs after if block - unable to use elif or else.*

Why does my ipython interpreter's continuation line break right after if block while only pressing RET once?

Comment: I think you got a faulty release.  There was a temporary bug in v 7 that accepted only one continuation line.  I saw it in function definitions.  You might try loading an update.  I retreated to v6.5, so I don't know the exact status of the v7 releases.

Comment: Earlier reports of this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52836676/ipython-ends-input-of-indented-blocks-after-first-newline, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52775562/multi-line-editing-broken-in-ipython-7-0-1, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52551878/problems-upgrading-ipython-prompt-toolkit-incompatibilities