# Ipython. How to continue code on the next line?

Tags: ipython

I've recently installed Ipython version 7.0.1 and I can't figure how to continue writing code on the next line.

E.g. the following executes upon pressing enter after the print statement.

```
def greeting():
    print("hi")
```

My previous version would have given me an indented newline, and upon pressing enter again(leaving the prior line blank) would then execute. I could then continue to write code within the function such as:

```
def greeting():
    print("hi")
    lst = []
    return lst
```

As it stands, I am simply unable to enter the second version of my function into ipython because it executes after the print statement.

; and \ do not work.

E.g.

```
def greeting():
    print("hi")\


def greeting():
    print("hi");
```

Comment: Do you mean adding an **empty** line? As far as I know, Ipython only executes that function definition if you enter an **empty** line? If so, just use a commented empty line.

Comment: Did you use `sep="\n"` parameter in print? And try use `c-m` shortcut.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my post to clarify the issue I'm experiencing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52912257/why-does-continuation-line-break-right-after-if-block-on-ipython - a known bug

Answer (score 1):

As of version 7.1.1 this issue appears to have been resolved. I was on version 7.0.1.

```
pip install ipython --upgrade
```