# Enter structured command to ipython in multiple lines

Tags: python, ipython

I want to write such a structured command in multiple lines

```
for i in range(10):
    if i > 2:
        print(i)
    else:
        print("else")
```

However, it break automatically

```
In [58]: for i in range(10): 
    ...:     if i > 2: 
    ...:         print(i)                                                                                         
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

I think it is facile to write as shell script in terminal

```
$ for i in 1 2 3
→ do echo $i
→ done
1
2
3
```

How could I set the ipython to control multiple lines input?

Comment: it works fine for me. see https://ibb.co/n9si00

Comment: after every line put spaces before code, and end statement with backslash. for example: ``...if i > 2:  \`` and so on.

Comment: how do you make it ?@Seenivasan

Comment: This is a temporary (hopefully) problem with a recent release of Ipython/Jupyter.  It's come up in other recent SO questions.  Solution - go back to 6.5.  Or use `ctrl-o` to continue with indented lines.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52912257/why-does-continuation-line-break-right-after-if-block-on-ipython