# Function object in spyder not working properly

Tags: python, spyder

When I am building a function in python, using spyder, the function object is not working properly.

e.g.,

```
def first_order(y,t):
    tau=5
```

After introducing the 2nd line it automatically closes the function. How can I change this behavior?

It used to be like this

```
    def first_order(y,t):

>             tau=5 
    ...: (first Enter, creates a new line)
(second Enter, to close the function)
```

Comment: please write an example of your problem and state the expected outcome

Comment: It doesn't seem like you did what it said. Function definition works fine in spyder

Comment: your indentation is wrong

Comment: Manuel, could you please tell me, does [the answer I've posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53223752/2749397) solve your problem? I ask because I'd prefer to remove it if it is not correct or, worse, misleading.  Thank you.

Comment: @user8408080 Manuel report is _mostly_ correct, they just had a wrong reason for the buggy behaviour.  It's not Spyder in itself, nor the the Python interpreter, but it's an issue with the interactive console used by Spyder, i.e.,  IPython. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53223752/2749397) below for details

Answer (score 0):

Spyder uses IPython in its interactive console.
What you report is a [bug in IPython 7.0](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/11334), so the cleanest solution is to upgrade to IPython 7.1.

<strike>As a stop gap measure, if your platform doesn't provide 7.1 yet, you can use  the key-chord `Ctrl-o` (instead of `Return`) to open a new line below the second line of the function definition and move there using the cursor key — after this maneuver the situation will be normal for the rest of the function definition.</strike>

*Update*

I knew that Spyder uses IPython, I didn't knew that it uses it via the `qtconsole` and the bug I described was still not fixed in 7.1 `qtconsole` (thank you Carlos Cordoba for pointing out).

The reason why OP has a problem still stands as valid, I fear that we have to wait 7.2 to have a fix for the `qtconsole` because the *ad interim* solution that I've described doesn't work in `qtconsole`

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) This is still an issue in IPython 7.1, so I think we need to change something in qtconsole to fix this.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba AH! Spyder uses qtconsole... The issue was solved in IPython 7.1 _"plain"_ console. I'll edit my answer because I feel it is still relevant re the diagnosis of the problem, if not for its resolution.  Thank you for pointing out my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This is a [bug](https://github.com/jupyter/qtconsole/issues/314) in the Qtconsole package and it'll be fixed in its **4.4.3** version, to be released today.